# convert 12 7-12 to superscript 12⁷⁻¹/² is there a way to reduce length of / and the 12 7-1/2 is in one cell. I converted it manually with code below

Tags: superscript

## function to convert to superscript

def get_super(x):
normal = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-=()"
super_s = "ᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾQᴿˢᵀᵁⱽᵂˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰᶦʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖ۹ʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁺⁻⁼⁽⁾"
res = x.maketrans(''.join(normal), ''.join(super_s))
return x.translate(res)

## display superscipt

print('12' + get_super('7-1/2')) # result 12⁷⁻¹/² the 12 added manually need to automate. have 12000 rows and 5 columns. will the elongated / affect calculations?

Comment: What do you mean by _the 12 7-1/2 is in one cell_?

Comment: the runner was in 12th position 7 -1/2 meters behind the winner. The 7-1/2 is to be a superscript to 12.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know what you mean by _is in one cell_, but I now take you mean one string value. - Next question: What exactly do you _need to automate_?